# C# plotting points of a line using 2 Points, calculating slope, and using for loop, but result is off by 10. How do I fix my formula?

Tags: c#, math, plot, graph, line

What I am trying to do ultimately is draw the pixels of a line using a custom software that does not have access to most drawing functions, so right now I am just trying to see if I can grab the coordinates of each pixel on the line using a For loop and print it out to the console. I am starting with 2 Point variables, p1 and p2, and calculating slope to plot it out. But I have 2 problems. First, it's not starting at 40, and second, it seems to have a range of 50 instead of 40 as I would expect. Does anyone know how to fix my formula to properly decrement X and plot the points?

Here is my C# code:

```
        Point p1 = new Point(40, 0);
        Point p2 = new Point(0, 100);
        
        var slope = (p2.Y - p1.Y)/(p2.X - p1.X);

        for (var y = p1.Y; y < p2.Y; y++)
        {
            var x = y/slope;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
        }
```

I am pretty sure my problem is with the following line, but not sure what it should be:

var x = y/slope;

I am expecting to loop through each point of Y and then calculate the point of X that corresponds to the slope that was calculated. But my output for X is not going from 40 down to 0 like I expect, it's going from 0 down to -49.

[image: Output]
[image: Output]

Comment: In addition to Quercus' answer, should you not add the `X` of the first point to your `x` calculation?

Comment: So, like this: "var x = p1.X + y/slope;"

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: This is getting me closer, but now X ranges from 40 down to -9.5

Comment: Line drawing is a bit more involved than this if the goal is for it to work in any direction - consider if you have a horizontal line where p1.Y == p2.Y and your loop does nothing. You'll need to establish the largest delta of the two axis first.

Comment: Personally I would probably just go with [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you @500, that was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Type `Point` holds integer `X` and `Y`, so your `slope` is also integer and is equal to: `100/40 = 2` (integer math).
Change `slope` calculation to:

```cs
var slope = (double)(p2.Y-p1.Y)/(p2.X-p1.X);
```

To have slope as floating point variable.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it's still going from 0 to -49 in the output, well -49.5 now.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the formula, pls see to [Equation](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/two-point-form/)

```
            Point p1 = new Point(40, 0);
            Point p2 = new Point(0, 100);

            var slope = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);

            for (var x = p1.X; x >=0; x--)
            {
                var y = slope*(x-p2.X)+p2.Y;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I will give this a try also. I am concerned that var x is being manually set to 40 rather than reading from p1, but I will worry about that later.

Comment: this does not work. It gives me the following: coordinates ranging from 40, 0 to 0, 80. Y does not go up to 100.

Comment: i edited my answer, but the previous result was also not wrong, it was by the first point (by p1)

Comment: This is not general use of course; it will only work in a very specific arrangement of the points (e.g. for starters, where p2 has an x value of 0).

Comment: @LukeBriggs, this is task related, so in your case you should choose the maximum by x

Comment: @MansurKurtov the question is to plot a line between 2 random points; `for (var x = p1.X; x >=0; x--)` makes multiple incorrect assumptions - if p1.x and p2.x are both negative, it's still a valid line, but this loop won't do anything for example. Also it assumes p2.x is 0 (because your loop stops there always). Thirdly it assumes p1.x > p2.x, which also isn't necessarily the case.